# Why is $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}-x \ne x - x$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}+x = x + x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

Let's say we're trying to solve the following limit:

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}-x$

One way to do this is to use conjugates which results in the following:

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle x}{\displaystyle\sqrt{x^2+x}+x}$

Here's my problem: For the latter, we can simplify it so we'd have

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle x}{\displaystyle\sqrt{x^2+x} + x} = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle x}{\displaystyle x+x}  = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle x}{\displaystyle 2x} = \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 2}$

but the same thing can't be done to the former. That is, we can't say

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}-x = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x - x = 0$

I believe this is issue comes from the last equality because $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x -x$ is like $\frac {0}{0}$; it's indeterminate but I'm not exactly sure.

***EDIT***

I'm so sorry I think I didn't phrase my question properly. My bad! I know why the two limits in the title are MUCH different; one tends to infinity whereas the other one has a finite value of $\frac{1}{2}$. I'm confused about why in the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\displaystyle x}{\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2+x} + x}$, we can say the denominator is $2x$ but in the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x} - x$ we can't say the square root is equal to $x$.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but nothing here is true.

Comment: @Aqua lol I was reading this thinking, either I'm crazy or has math just changed in the few years since I left school.

Comment: All your equations here are rather dubious IMHO.

Comment: @Aqua Other than the parts involving $x-x$, the rest is actually from a textbook and the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$  so I think the second and third limit are correct.

Comment: @Aqua Would you please say which one is wrong? I had a typo in the third limit and now it's fixed. It might have been that.

Comment: $(x+\frac12)^2=x^2+x+1/4$. So for large $x$ the square root $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ is surely closer to $x+\frac12$ than $x$.

Comment: But, your notation is somewhat confused. The $x$ in $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ is a dummy variable. So whatever is on the right hand side MUST NOT HAVE ANY $x$ in it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen After we use conjugates in the limit I wanted to evaluate, the denominator would have a value of $2x$ which would cancel out with the $x$ in the numerator. Hence the $x$ in the RHS.

Comment: I realize what your question is. But. No, when you go to the limit. All the $x$s must disappear.

Comment: Anyway, the answer to your dilemma is that $\sqrt{x^2+x}\approx x$ for large values of $x$. For the purposes of determining that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x}+x=\infty$, this approximation is good enough. But for the purposes of calculating $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x}-x$ the approximation is too crude. The calculation with the conjugates and all that reveals that $\sqrt{x^2+x}\approx x+\frac12$ is a better approximation, and good enough for the purposes of that other limit. For some other purposes you would need even better approximations.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh that makes sense. Is there sort of a "guideline" that says when an approximation is good or not?

Comment: It depends. Subtracting large, nearly identical quantities always leads to loss of accuracy. Something you may have seen with pocket calculators also :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is meaningless state that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}-x \ne x - x$  and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}+x = x + x$ we should state that

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}-x = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac1{2}+o(1/x)=\frac12$$

and

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}+x = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}  2x+o(1)=\infty$$

the explanation in both case is in binomial first order approximation that is

$$\sqrt{x^2+x}=x\left(1+\frac1x\right)^\frac12= x\left(1+\frac1{2x}+o\left(\frac1x\right)\right)=x+ \frac1{2}+o\left(1\right) $$

which means that for $x$ large we have

$$\sqrt{x^2+x}\sim x+ \frac1{2}$$

and therefore

$$\sqrt{x^2+x}-x \sim \frac 12$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+x}+x \sim 2x+\frac 12$$

---

**Edit**

Note that for $\frac{x}{ \sqrt{x^2+x} + x}$ it is not correct to state that the denominator is $2x$ the complete steps are

$$\frac{x}{ \sqrt{x^2+x} + x}=\frac x x \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+1/x} + 1} \to \frac12$$

For  $\sqrt{x^2+x} - x$ indeed is not correct take$ \sqrt{x^2+x}=x$ what is true is that $\sqrt{x^2+x}\sim x+\frac12$.

If we use that approximation, it works with both limits. In this particular case first order approximation works and we can use it to evaluate both limits.

Comment: I'm sorry but we haven't learned about the $o$ notation and binomial first order approximation.

Comment: You can also use rationalization, the main issue doesn’t change, the statements in the title are meaningless. The two limit are simply different, one tends to 1/2 and the other to infinity.

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade Even if you are not familiar with the little o notation, maybe you can appreciate the reason for which the two limit are so different. Indeed for $x$ large  the $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ term  behaves as $x+ \frac1{2}$ plus other terms which becomes negligible as $x$ becomes large and large.

Comment: Ohhhh. I think I didn't phrase my question properly. My bad! I know why the two limits are MUCH different; one tends to infinity whereas the other one has a finite value of $\frac{1}{2}$. I'm confused about why in the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\displaystyle x}{\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2+x} + x}$, we can say the denominator is $2x$ but in the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x} - x$ we can't say the square root is equal to $x$.

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade Form here $\frac{x}{ \sqrt{x^2+x} + x}$ it is not correct to state that the denominator is $2x$, the complete steps are $$\frac{x}{ \sqrt{x^2+x} + x}=\frac x x \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+1/x} + 1} \to \frac12$$

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade For  $\sqrt{x^2+x} - x$ indeed is not correct take$ \sqrt{x^2+x}=x$ what is true is that $\sqrt{x^2+x}\sim x+\frac12$. If we use that approximation, it works with both limits. In this particular case first order approximation works and we can use it to evaluate both limits.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. Thank you so much! I'm so  sorry I wasted your time. Please add the comments to your answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$ (1\pm f(x))^n \approx 1 \pm nf(x) $$
for $f(x) \to 0$.
The root from your question can be rewritten as:
$$ \sqrt{x^2+x} = x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} \approx x(1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x}) $$
becasue from your limit $ 1/x \to 0 $. From here you can get the answers.

Comment: Why the downvote :( ?